# React Higher Order Component does not work correctly

Tags: reactjs, components

I write a react higher order component likes below:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native'
const dismissKeyboard = require('dismissKeyboard')
export default (WrappedComponent) => class AutoHideKeyboard extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={dismissKeyboard}>
                <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )
    }
}
```

But it's onPress function doesn't work when I press the page.

Then I try not to use higer order component,instead I directly wrap the component like below:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native'
const dismissKeyboard = require('dismissKeyboard')
export default class Demo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={dismissKeyboard}>
                <View>
                   //some components like TextInput
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )
    }
}
```

This time it does work.
Why these two ways behave differently?

Comment: A React component must be either a function that returns JSX elements to be rendered, or a class with a render method. In your first example you're trying to define a function that returns a class, which is not a correct way to define a component.

Comment: Please include your actual code in your question, not screenshots.

Comment: @Assan I don't think I define a wrong higher order component.Refer to this article https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.30u53gcjn

Comment: Then you'd use such higher order component differently, I suppose. Something like `const Wrapper = AutoHideKeyboard(View); return <Wrapper />;` Is that what you're doing?

Comment: @Assan That's how I am using it.

Comment: @Assan Actually,if I only attach style prop to the TouchableWithoutFeedback component,it does perform well.However,onPress prop doesn't work corretly

Comment: @Jordan Thanks for your advice.Pls see my question again

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @Jordan I mean when I tap the page,it doesn't trigger the onPress function

Comment: @Jordan I have solved this problem by using TouchableHighLight instead of TouchableWithoutFeedback.I don't know why these two components behave differently